# Slow down animation in AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to use AndroidSlidingUpPanel library. I want to change it for slowing down the animation when I click a view from dragView. By default it expands or collapse the dragView very fast. 
Can I slow it down?
Is there a way to make it fast initially and then slow as it readched end?

Reference library link:
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Following is my xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/dragView">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Main Content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dragView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/graphic" >
            </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_demo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:background="#ffffff">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/follow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```